# How to format Power Automate's "Create HTML table" to display hyperlink in email pointing to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, power-automate

With a SharePoint List as a data source, I have a Power Automate workflow that groups by a field, then emails unique people a list of stuff that's applicable to them. In the email, there should be hyperlinks pointing to editable SP List items. I have the flow working except the hyperlinks in email are not working as expected. Here is the
[body of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0bID.png) instead of the expected [body of email with hyperlinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X89JV.png). I used "concat('Link')" as a value in "Create HTML table" step and "replace(replace(replace(body('Create_HTML_table'), '<a href="', ''), '<a/>', '')" in "Send an Email" step per [this article](https://faustocapellan.com/2021/01/26/how-to-5-format-links-sent-via-email-in-power-automate/): . Here is an [illustration of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SsE6.png).

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly, in the list of available fields, use '*Link to item*' rather than '*Title*' for your link, whether the Title links or not.*

*Secondly; you can just type the special characters (like the HTML tag greater than ">") normally in the replace, like I have below. However I believe that the two solutions I've given you will perhaps provide a more slick email.*

### Logic Solution

Rather than relying on nested replace functions, you can parse the created html and make an cleaner result.

1. Still create the HTML table, but in the item value, put link then insert the SharePoint ID from the dynamic content. If you run this, as an example, the result for the 10th ever item in the list will format like this:

   ```
   link10
   ```
2. Now run a Apply to each on the Get items action you made the table from, and for each item, you will replace the link# with the required url from the Link to item field in an html link wrapped around the title.
3. Insert that amended code into the email.

---

For the flow I have gone as verbose as I can to ensure the logic is obvious, it stands to reason that much of this might be minimised (image after description):

1. **Get items** - SharePoint pull, no filter, only 3 items (car, boat, plane).
2. **Create HTML table** - Details:

   - '`From`' - The "value" dynamic content from 'Get items'.

     ```
       @{outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']}
     ```
   - '`Columns`' - "Custom" with one entry:

     - '`Header`' - "item"
     - '`Value`' - "`link@{item()?['ID']}`"
3. **Variables** - Initialise these variables:

   - `linkVAR` - Initialize an empty string variable.
   - `htmlTabStVAR` - Initialize an empty string variable.
   - `findVAR` - Initialize an empty string variable.
   - `linkVAR` - Initialize a string variable with the output of the 'Create HTML table' action.
4. Apply to each - 'Select an output from previous steps' must be the same as the table in #2.

   - **Set htmlTabStVAR** - This should be the output of the Set htmlTabEnVAR

     ```
       @{variables('htmlTabEnVAR')}
     ```
   - **Set findVAR** - This sets the variable the replace function will use to find the right item:

     ```
       link@{items('Apply_to_each')?['ID']}
     ```
   - **Set linkVAR** - This sets the desired HTML for the link:

     ```
       <a href="@{items('Apply_to_each')?['{Link}']}">@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Title']}</a>
     ```
   - **Set htmlTabStVAR** - This should be the output of the Set htmlTabEnVAR

     ```
       replace(variables('htmlTabStVAR'), variables('findVAR'), variables('linkVAR'))
     ```
5. Setup your email, here is the body that I used:

   ```
   <p>this works</p>
   <p>table:</p>
   @{variables('htmlTabEnVAR')}
   ```

Here's the flow image:
[image]

Here's the email, and the resultant HTML (from the flow history):
[image]

```
<p>this works</p>
<p>table:</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="https://yourCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/spSite/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=ETCETCETC">car</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="https://yourCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/spSite/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=ETCETCETC">boat</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="https://yourCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/spSite/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=ETCETCETC">plane</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To minimise the Apply to each you can remove the link and find variables and use this, longer, replace function in the expression for the htmlTabEnVAR:

```
replace(variables('htmlTabStVAR'), concat('link', items('Apply_to_each')?['ID']), concat('<a href="', items('Apply_to_each')?['{Link}'], '">', items('Apply_to_each')?['Title'], '</a>'))
```

---

### One Step Minimised

Fair warning; if you're not going to use the unique characters I use below, test which ones don't parse well in flow, first, I found some that caused issues, like "æ".

So, in order to minimise the whole thing in to one step after the HTML creation, you can use the email section like this:

1. In the HTML table, use unlikely characters to wrap the ID and Title fields from SharePoint. I've used "ĐĐĐ", "œœœ", and "ĐœĐœĐ":

   ```
   ĐĐĐ@{item()?['ID']}œœœ@{item()?['Title']}ĐœĐœĐ
   ```
2. In the email, go to the body, and ensure you have placed the following expression in the "Code view" (click the '`</>`' button), replacing:

- `[COMPANY]` with your company sub-domain,
- `[SITE]` with the relevant SharePoint site
- `[LISTNAME]` with the relevant list name

  ```
   replace(replace(replace(string, 'ĐĐĐ', '<a href="https://[COMPANY].sharepoint.com/sites/[SITE]/Lists/[LISTNAME]/DispForm.aspx?ID='), 'œœœ', '">'), 'ĐœĐœĐ', '</a>')
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this extensive walk-through. I suspect this solution will work for the hyperlinks part, but not the "groups by a field" part of my scenario. Specifically, it looks like it'll list all items hyperlinked (perfect), but simultaneously lose listing a group of the items by another field. I have a "Person" field where Person A owns a boat, car, and airplane, Person B owns a ship and submarine. I shall report back after trying it out, thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, I'd read: "_I have a Power Automate workflow that groups by a field, then emails unique people a list of stuff that's applicable to them._" Then: "_I have the flow working except the hyperlinks in email are not working as expected._" That indicates the only part not working was the hyperlinks.

I'd provided the logic to insert however needed. It should go without saying on any flow, that there's _way_ more that can be done within a grander flow.

However, if you provide your base flow (blot out private parts), I can work it in. That said, I do believe this resolves the issue indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my lack of clarity: we're both correct...I have the group by working as stated...but now I can't get my group by and your hyperlink solution working side by side. It looks like the issue is between the concat() in "Create HTML table" and/or replace() in the email body. I have tried to illustrate the issue further in the attachments, please refer to those. Thank you!

[page 1 of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0CCh.jpg);
[page 2 of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T9r8.jpg)